# How can I increase the length of the node editor's "name" input field?

Tags: node-editor, customization

Here's an image of what I mean:

[image: Node Editor Field]

It gets annoying when working with names that are longer than the input box.

Anyone know how to do this?

Comment: Not possible unless you modify the source code I'm afraid :)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I only know how to do it by modifying the source.

Right-click on the input field in the Shader Editor and select "Edit Source".

[image: Edit Source in dropdown]

In the status bar, Blender should tell you something like `See 'space_node.py' in the text editor`. Open the Text Editor and switch to the file it told you to. The cursor should appear near the end of this section. Add the highlighted line.

[image: Text Editor]

(Increase `18` if you want to make it even longer.)

Run the script (with the arrow button to the right of the input field). You should see the change take effect in the Shader Editor immediately. When you've found a number you like, save the script (Text > Save) to persist your changes.

Comment: Thanks very much.

Comment: Wow, that's a cool function - Blender is the first program I saw that let's you directly edit it's source code !